# Peano Curve in python tkinter recursive

Tags: python, recursion, drawing, tkinter, curves

I'm trying to find out how to draw a peano curve in tkinter. Should I use `create_line`?

My second question is how to start writing peano_curve function recursively: where to start drawing, setting steps, setting shutdown condition and so on. Can anyone help me to write this function? I haven't found anything useful on the Internet so far.

Comment: Give it a try on your own and ask specific questions as you get stuck.

Comment: ok i will try (again) but it wouldn't be easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Your distribution of Python should come with demo scripts which use [tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html#module-Tkinter) (and the [turtle](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) module) to draw fractal curves. (Talk about batteries being included! :))

Running

```
python fractalcurves.py
```

draws the [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve):

[image]

You could study this code and modify it to draw the [Peano curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

---

On Ubuntu 11.10 the file is located at `/usr/share/doc/python2.7/examples/Demo/turtle/tdemo_fractalcurves.py`. If the demo scripts were not packaged with in your distribution of Python, you can also find it in the source code repository [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/58bd6a58365d/Lib/turtledemo/fractalcurves.py).

Comment: Very bad answer. A peano curve divide the space into 9 tiles.

Answer (score 1):

**Drawing** such curves is usually pretty easy. Use "turtle graphics" and **L-Systems**, and it should be fairly easy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system

The Peano curve as L-System then just is this:

```
F -> F+F-F-F-F+F+F+F-F
```

with 90° rotations on `+` and `-`, and `F` either being recursion or drawing (at the desired level).

Comment: can i combine turtle and tkinter?

Comment: turtle graphics is a technique, not a library. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics